# iOS 14 widget UserDefaults(suiteName:) not working

Tags: swiftui, widget

Xcode 12.0 (12A7208)
MacOS 10.15.6 (19G2021)

1. Create an new SwiftUI project.
2. Add Capability App Groups.
3. Create an new Target Widget Extension, add Capability App Groups.
4. In Main App use `UserDefaults(suiteName:).set` to save an Int data.
5. In Widget, Under `getTimeline(for:in:completion:)` function just call `UserDefaults(suiteName:).value`,cannot get the Int Data. But in Main App can.

`suiteName` is started with `group.`, and it is same in Widget and Main App.

quite confused...

Comment: Have you added the App Group to both Targets?

Comment: Yes. I'm quite sure

Comment: @dushandz same issue here, did you fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

For any future readers I found this error - "Code Signing Error - Verify the value of the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS" which was in a very un-obvious place.

To fix:

1. Go to your new Target
2. Go to Build Settings
3. Go to the Signing section. Make sure you have an .entitlement file assigned to both Release and Debug. An entitlement file should've been automatically created in your folder structure. You just need to make sure you get the path correct eg. "Widget/WidgetExtension.entitlement"

Comment: man, this helped me a lot. i had this set for Debug only, not for release, therefore my app and extension couldn't use shared objects when launched via TestFlight!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure u've added app groups to both configurations (debug and release).

[image]